# Returning the minimum value of a Stack

Tags: java, stack, queue

I have a method called `removeMin` that takes a `Stack<CalendarDate>` as a parameter and removes the minimum value (earliest date in this case) from the stack and returns it. However, I'm not getting the value I anticipated. I believe I understand stacks adequately. Here is my method.

```
public static CalendarDate removeMin(Stack<CalendarDate> stack) {
        Queue<CalendarDate> aux = new LinkedList<CalendarDate>();
        CalendarDate min = stack.peek();
        if(stack.size() < 1) {
            return null;
        }

        while (!stack.empty()) {
            CalendarDate c = stack.pop();
            aux.add(c);
            if(c.compareTo(min) == -1) {
                min = c;
            }
            aux.add(c);
        }

        while (!aux.isEmpty()) {
            if (aux.remove().compareTo(min) == 1) {
                stack.push(aux.remove());
            }
        }

        while (!stack.empty()) {
            aux.add(stack.pop());
        }

        while (!aux.isEmpty()) {
            stack.push(aux.remove());
        }

        return min;

    }
```

Here is also my testing code in my main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // store some dates so they can be reused
        CalendarDate[] store = {new CalendarDate(1,2,10), new CalendarDate(1,1,10), new CalendarDate(12,30,10)};
        Stack<CalendarDate> testAll = new Stack<CalendarDate>();
        for (CalendarDate i: store) {
            testAll.push(i); // build a Stack
        }
        for (int i = 1;i <= 9;i++) {
            testAll.push(new CalendarDate(1,1,10));
        }
        System.out.println(Chapter14.removeMin(testAll));
    }
```

As you can see, I have made a stack with 1/1/10, 1/2/10, and 12/30/10. After I run the removeMin method, it SHOULD return 12/30/10 because it comes BEFORE 1/1/10 right? Well, my output says otherwise, since I am getting `1/1/10` instead of `12/30/10`as the result from removeMin. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: `if (aux.remove().compareTo(min) == 1) {
                stack.push(aux.remove());
            }` why remove twice?

Comment: I should have probably put that in a variable now that I think about it. :D

Comment: You can find the stack min by `CalendarDate min = stack.stream().min((i1, i2) -> CalendarDate.compare(i1, i2)).get();`

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the dates appear to be in mm/dd/yy format. If so, then the dates are:
**January 2nd 2010

January 1st 2010

December 30th 2010**

This followed by 9 more copies of  **January 1st 2010.**

Since January 1st comes before all other dates, 1 copy of January 1st should be removed.
To test this you might try looping removeMin until the stack is empty. It should start by removing 10 copies of January 1st, followed by January 2nd, and finally December 30th.